# Why always fsck my disk?

Tags: debian, disk

Recently,there is a error info on disk during booting:

[image]

I have to type `fsck -y /dev/sda4` behind `(initramfs)`,then reboot to enter into my os.
Is the disk `/dev/sda4` going to be broken?

os info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.178-3 (2023-04-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You do do fsck manually. There is some corruption, so programmers decided they do not want responsibility, so they do not fix it automatically. OTOH nearly nobody has knowledge to answer question in a different way then default. So run the command manually to correct the filesystem, and then it should be ok.

Comment: At a _guess_ either you've got hardware corruption or you're not shutting your system down completely before powering it off

Comment: Did this happen one time or is it happening every time you reboot?

Comment: Often ,not everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this just happens but it should be very rare.

You didn't say what filesystem this was nor how mission-critical the host is (the latter is particularly relevant to how you address this).

Of course, you already have a tested backup/restore plan so you are prepared for a complete failure of the device. And you run a managed shutdown everytime rather than just pulling the power cord out.

I suggest you want to start capturing smartctl stats regularly (use a cron job) and checking for high/increasing errors or reallocated sectors. Either will indicate an issue with the hardware. If the machine is being rebooted regularly and the problem recurrs - the disk (or controller, but more likely the disk) is failing and needs replaced. If it "always" happens and you are shutting it down cleanly, then go buy a new disk now.